# How do I configure a backend for Stripe to implement in a Swift App?

Tags: ios, swift, heroku, stripe-payments, alamofire

I've been researching for the last couple of hours and have been struggling to understand how to implement a backend for Stripe.  I am not very experienced and some of the iOS Stripe documentation is confusing me.  A lot of resources recommend setting up a backend using Heroku/PHP and using Alamofire or AFNetworking, but I'm not very familiar with it.  I know this is kind of a dumb question but I'm trying my best to learn!  Could anyone give me an explanation on how to setup a simple backend/explain Alamofire or recommend resources on how I can implement Stripe properly?

Comment: You can find an example iOS backend here: https://github.com/stripe/example-ios-backend. This backend is usable with the iOS example included in the bindings: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/tree/master/Example

Comment: I have posted a vague answer below, however start coding and show us what you have done and then we can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to learn how to do this you should do it in Javascript / Node.JS and use something like Heroku to setup an Express Server.

On the iOS side I would use Alamofire which will allow you to easily make API calls from your Swift App. The implementation of which would look something like this (For creating a new customer):

```
let apiURL = "https://YourDomain.com/add-customer"
let params = ["email": "hello@test.com"]
let heads = ["Accept": "application/json"]

Alamofire.request(.POST, apiURL, parameters: params, headers: heads)
     .responseJSON { response in
         print(response.request)  // original URL request
         print(response.response) // URL response
         print(response.data)     // server data
         print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

         if let JSON = response.result.value {
             print("JSON: \(JSON)")
         }
     }
```

On the server side, assuming you are using Express have something like this:

```
    app.post('/add-customer', function (req, res) {
    stripe.customers.create(
        { email: req.body.email },
        function(err, customer) {
            err; // null if no error occured
            customer; // the created customer object

            res.json(customer) // Send newly created customer back to client (Swift App)
        }
    );
});
```